# There are no property pages for the selection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Hey guys my friend sent me his vb.net project made in VS2012 but I'm using VS2010. Now I can't open the file, it says 'This project is incompatible with current version of Visual Studio'. I have Googled it out and they said I need to change format version to v11 instead of 12 and also change target framework to 4.0. However, I am only able to change the format version to v11, but unable to change the target framework since I have nothing to access in the properties , as it shows 'there are no property pages for the selection'. How can I fix this?? Anyway to change the framework without going into properties??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I've figured it out guys.

open up the .vcxproj file using note pad and change the number from 4.5 to 4.0,so it should look like this

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```